# После выполнения функции INSERT выводится тот же список, что и до ее выполнения. В чем проблема?

Tags: c++, список

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int maxlen = 100;

struct LIST
{
    int elem[maxlen];
    int last;  //индекс последнего элемента списка
};
// Вставка
bool INSERT(int x, int p, LIST L)
{
    if (p > L.last + 2 || p < 1)
        return false;
    else if (p < L.last + 2)//вставка не в конец списка
    {
        for (int i = L.last; i >= p - 1; i--)
            /*перемещаем на одну позицию вниз, начиная с последнего*/
            L.elem[i + 1] = L.elem[i];
    }
    L.last++;
    L.elem[p - 1] = x;
    cout << L.last << endl;
    return true;
};

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    LIST cpisok;
    //Начальный список
    cpisok.elem[0] = 5;
    cpisok.elem[1] = 0;
    cpisok.elem[2] = 9;
    cpisok.last = 2;
    cout << setw(18) << "Номер элемента" << setw(18) << "Значение элемента" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= cpisok.last; i++) {
        cout << setw(18) << i+1 << setw(18) << cpisok.elem[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "Что вы хотите сделать?" << endl << "1) Ввести новый элемента списка";
    cout << endl << "2) Удалить элемент списка" << endl << "3) Найти элемент списка" << endl;
    cout << "Введите цифру: ";

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 1) {
        int x, p;
        cout << endl << "Введите элемент: ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << endl << "Введите позицию, в которую хотите вставить этот элемент: ";
        cin >> p;
        INSERT(x, p, cpisok);
        cout << cpisok.last;
        cout << endl << setw(18) << "Номер элемента" << setw(18) << "Значение элемента" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i <= cpisok.last; i++) {
            cout << setw(18) << i + 1 << setw(18) << cpisok.elem[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в функцию

```
bool INSERT(int x, int p, LIST L)
```

передается копия списка, так что после вызова

```
INSERT(x, p, cpisok);
```

ваш `cpisok` остается неизменным - вы поменяли копию.

Передавайте `LIST` по ссылке.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!